# jQuery - Programatically insert a value into text field then trigger click

Tags: jquery

There could be a better way to do this, but for now, I need to do it this way.

I have a google maps geocode thing going on with input field as follows:

```
<input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" style="width:400px;" value="#url.address#" />
<input id="find" type="button" value="find" />
```

Notice the geocode field is autopopulated. Normally a user would manually enter this value before hitting "Find", but in this file the user is updating their record, so I'm autopopulating the address.

I'm using the following code to trigger a click on the Find button, which would normally generate a google map based on the entered address. This works fine when the user manually enters the address before hitting "Find".

Don't be phased by the `<cfoutput>` tags. This is a coldfusion template and that works fine.

```
$(function(){
    var address = '<cfoutput>#url.address#</cfoutput>' || "";

    if(address.length != 0){
        $("#find").trigger("click"); // doesn't work 
        /*$("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");*/ // doesn't work either                    
    }

    $("#find").click(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
    });
})
```

This doesn't work, nothing seems to happen. If I click the Find button manually, it works. Not sure, but I think it's because the geocode field is not manually entered. If that's the case, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn it around. When you trigger the `click`, your event hasn't been created yet.

```
$(function(){
    var address = '<cfoutput>#url.address#</cfoutput>' || "";

    $("#find").click(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
    });

    if(address.length != 0){
        $("#find").trigger("click");
   }
})
```

Comment: Gah, yep that did it, thanks. Will mark as correct when they let me.

Answer (score 2):

i think with trigger("click") you cannot perfectly replicate real mouse click. Insted why dont you do:

```
if(address.length != 0){

        $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");                 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this should do the trick:

```
$("#find").click();
```